# Run Macro with vb.net Application to format Word Documents

Tags: vb.net

I have a macro files with file extension of .DO Files(.DO). I Open a file through vb.net

application and to also open a macro. by using that macro I need to format that word Document. I

tried a lot but no use . I try to Select some area of word file but it will leads to error:

> Object reference not set to instance of object

```
Private sub beginFormatting
    ls_inipath = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath & "\"
    ls_Document = GetIniValue("Remove_Pages", "doc_name", txtFileName.Text)

    Dim what As Object = Word.WdGoToItem.wdGoToLine
    Dim which As Object = Word.WdGoToDirection.wdGoToLast

    Dim SelectionOne As Selection

    Dim returnValue As Range = SelectionOne.GoTo(what, which, Nothing, 
   Nothing)

    SelectionOne.EndKey(WdUnits.wdStory, WdMovementType.wdMove)
end sub
```

Comment: This is not a C# question. Please don't tag questions incorrectly.

Comment: `Dim SelectionOne As Selection` followed by `... = SelectionOne.GoTo`.  You never set `SelectionOne` to anything, so it is `NULL` when you attempt to use it.

Comment: sorry I m new to Stack overflow. Anyways i follow this in future posts. Thanks